# Apache camel Quartz endpoints : rescheduling at runtime

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to change cron expression of camel quartzendpoint at runtime using jmx or so ?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the route itself (including configuration of the quartz endpoint). As an example you can see how Camel plugin of Hawt.io (http://hawt.io/plugins/camel/) does it

Comment: Yes the quartz plugin in hawtio actually uses Quartz JMX to rescheduled at runtime. But this reqires to enable Quartz JMX, and also its native JMX API is not easy to work with, so we added a facade in hawtio. But the point is that its doable

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could experiment with `CamelContext` and see if you can add new routes at runtime.